# The pictures are still vertical

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

The pictures on my website are arranged vertically, I would like them to be horizontal.
For this I used jQuery Mansonry.
I added 2 gemfile and And then I edited the files as in the documentation and book.
Website does not show an error, but the picture are still vertical ;/

```
 gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
 gem 'masonry-rails'
```

.

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

.

```
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

.

```
/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

.

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery.turbolinks
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require masonry/jquery.masonry
 //= require_tree .
```

.

```
/app/assets/javascripts/pins.coffee
```

.

```
 $('#pins').imagesLoaded ->
 $('#pins').masonry
 itemSelector: '.box'
 isFitWidth: true
```

.

.

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/pins.scss
```

.

```
 #pins {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .box {
 margin: 5px;
 width: 214px;
 }

 .box img {
 width: 100%;
 }
```

.

```
 /app/views/pins/index.html.erb
```

.

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
<div class="box">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %><br/>
<div class="panel-body">
<%= pin.description %><br/>
</div>
<% if pin.user == current_user %>
<div class="panel-footer">
<%= link_to 'edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %><br/>
<%= link_to 'delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure' } %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, the site works very well, but nothing has changed since I added the gems and extra lines in the code, everything works as before